# How to bring different elements into the viewport with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 elements that show/hide their contents when clicked on.

What I am aiming for:  Click on element 1, brings the entire div into view.  If I then click on element 2, the second div is brought into view.

What happens currently:  Click on element 1, brings the entire div into view.  Scroll down a bit and click on element 2, it scrolls back up to display the entire first div instead of the second div.

I believe the issue is that I have .content as the parameter in the scrollTop function but I haven't been able to figure out what I should put in there to address the issue.

My jquery/javascript is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flippy1").click(function(){

        $(this).parent().children(".content").slideToggle(); //toggles the content

        setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('body').animate({scrollTop:$('.content').offset().top},200) 
        }, 200);   //delay of 200 ms to let the entire slidetoggle animation finish, then scrolls to the top of the div

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">

         <div class="flippy1">
            <h2>Experience</h2>
         </div>

         <div class="content">
           content goes here
         </div>

     </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">

         <div class="flippy1">
            <h2>Dogs</h2>
         </div>

         <div class="content">
          contents goes here
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="flippy1">
            <h2>Cats</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
         more content
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Comment: If element 1 is `$(".flippy1")`, then what is element 2? I see no JavaScript related to any click event other than on `.flippy1` element.

Comment: Sure, one moment.  Also to clarify, flippy1 is a div class, not an ID.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me has been to use `$("html,body")` when animating `scrollTop` property. Some browsers do not play nicely with `$("body")` alone, although I have no proper explanation for this.

Second problem is you're referencing `$(".content")` in your timeout function. This animates `scrollTop` to the first occurrence of `.content`, not necessarily the clicked occurrence. But, we can do one better:

Third, and not a problem but a better way to handle, is to use the callback function of `slideToggle`: this function is code that gets executed *only after* slideToggle finishes. Do this rather than set a timeout. Timeout length is arbitrary, for example in a very old, very slow browser, 200ms may not be long enough duration to wait.

See the updates below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flippy1").click(function(){

        $(this).parent().children(".content").slideToggle( function(){
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top},200);
        });

    });
});
```

If you want to scroll to the top including the headline, simply grab the parent again and use *its* `offset` instead.

This line:

```
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top},200);
```

becomes:

```
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $(this).parent().offset().top},200);
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/nb0fvu3u/

Parent example here: https://jsfiddle.net/nb0fvu3u/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and for the explanation.  This solved my issue, and I see why the callback function instead of the timeout is better as well.  Much easier instead of having to play around with getting the correct timing.  Thank you again.